# Log a link to a source code in Firefox console

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am currently writing a logger that uses a console.log(). As I call to logger method instead of a console.log(), every log line shows the same position on the source code that corresponds to the linea where is the call to console.log().
I would like to include a link in the message that can show the line which is the origin of the log.

In Google Chrome it is possible to log an URL with a line number and column number (separated by colon) and it is automatically converted to a link. If I click on the link, I can view the source code at the specified line.
Here is an example:

```js
// press F12 and click on link in the console log, this will open the source code in the "Sources" tab at line-column 3:5
console.log('http://akfs.nspmotion.com/test/example.js:3:5');
```

```html
<script src="http://akfs.nspmotion.com/test/example.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this in the Firefox console?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you desire. Please post a pic, or some additional description. Part of my confusion is that for nearly every `console.log()` there is a link to the right of the output which shows the script name, the line number and position in the line where the `console.log()` occurs. The file name is a link which will open in either the debugger or in a separate tab and show the full contents of the JavaScript file along with having jumped to the line number. What beyond this are you looking for?

Comment: It appears you have put an invisible URL to JSFiddle in your question. Please [edit] the question to include the code from JSFiddle into your question. You should consider placing it in a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). You, probably, were informed when attempting to post this question that links to JSFiddle must include code. Why did you not just include the single line of code in the question? We are not permitted, due to copyright issues, to just copy the code in for you. You will need to [edit] the question.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already included a snippet and added an explanation of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't believe that what you specifically want is possible.  However, you may get something close by using [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace).

Answer (score 4):

The feature that logged URLs including row and column information are linked to the Debugger doesn't exist yet in the Firefox DevTools. Therefore I've requested it now in [bug 1360447](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1360447).

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this exact issue for one of my codebases I couldn't find any way to create a string that when printed to the firefox (113.0.2) console would link back to the source file/line the way that the standard console.log(*) functions do.

My solution is to print a CSS formatted log via 'groupCollapsed' and then inside the group print the trace (which although it contains logging-class-junk stack parts, still produces clickable links which will take you to your source in firefox's debug panel:

```html
// Configure logging styling and function using a bit field
let consoleCSS = "background-color: white; color: black";
let consoleFunc = console.log;
if((logItem.level & CRITICAL) !== 0) { consoleCSS =      "background-color: #FDF2F5; color: #A4000F"; consoleFunc = console.error; }
else if((logItem.level & ERROR)    !== 0) { consoleCSS = "background-color: #FDF2F5; color: #A4000F"; consoleFunc = console.error; }
else if((logItem.level & TRACE)    !== 0) { consoleCSS = "background-color: white; color: black";     consoleFunc = console.trace;}
else if((logItem.level & WARN)     !== 0) { consoleCSS = "background-color: #FFFBD6; color: #715100"; consoleFunc = console.warn;}
else if((logItem.level & INFO)     !== 0) { consoleCSS = "background-color: white; color: black";     consoleFunc = console.info;}
else if((logItem.level & DEBUG)    !== 0) { consoleCSS = "background-color: white; color: black";     consoleFunc = console.debug;}
else if((logItem.level & LOG)      !== 0) { consoleCSS = "background-color: white; color: black";     consoleFunc = console.log;}

if(logItem.level)
{
    // Print a formatted log message with timestamp, level, component and message
    const logMessage = `${logItem.timestamp}: ${logItem.level.toString} : ${logItem.component} :  ${logItem.content}`;
    //print a collapsed group styled to look appropriate but holding a stack trace inside
    console.groupCollapsed( "%c%s",consoleCSS,logMessage );            

    //print message with normal console func - log, error, warn, etc
    consoleFunc( logMessage );

    //output a stack trace (which is clickable in firefox)
    console.trace();

    //close the console group
    console.groupEnd();
}
```

Here is output in chrome
[image: Chrome console output]

and firefox
[image: Firefox formatted output with clickable links to source files]